# Getting error in iOS Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I update the Cocos2D version 2.0.0 to Cocos2D version 3.0.0 but i getting these error, please Help me. Thank you.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ChipmunkBody", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CCPhysicsBody.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ChipmunkCircleShape", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CCPhysicsShape.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ChipmunkConstraint", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CCPhysicsJoint.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ChipmunkDampedSpring", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CCPhysicsJoint.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ChipmunkPinJoint", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CCPhysicsJoint.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ChipmunkPivotJoint", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CCPhysicsJoint.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ChipmunkPolyShape", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CCPhysicsShape.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ChipmunkSegmentShape", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CCPhysicsShape.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ChipmunkSlideJoint", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CCPhysicsJoint.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ChipmunkSpace", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterCallWildcardBeginA", referenced from:
      _PhysicsBegin in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterCallWildcardBeginB", referenced from:
      _PhysicsBegin in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterCallWildcardPostSolveA", referenced from:
      _PhysicsPostSolve in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterCallWildcardPostSolveB", referenced from:
      _PhysicsPostSolve in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterCallWildcardPreSolveA", referenced from:
      _PhysicsPreSolve in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterCallWildcardPreSolveB", referenced from:
      _PhysicsPreSolve in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterCallWildcardSeparateA", referenced from:
      _PhysicsSeparate in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterCallWildcardSeparateB", referenced from:
      _PhysicsSeparate in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterGetBodies", referenced from:
      _PhysicsBegin in CCPhysicsNode.o
      _PhysicsPreSolve in CCPhysicsNode.o
      _PhysicsPostSolve in CCPhysicsNode.o
      _PhysicsSeparate in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterGetContactPointSet", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair contacts] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterGetFriction", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair friction] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterGetRestitution", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair restitution] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterGetShapes", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair shapeA:shapeB:] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterGetSurfaceVelocity", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair surfaceVelocity] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterGetUserData", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair userData] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterIgnore", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair ignore] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterSetFriction", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair setFriction:] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterSetRestitution", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair setRestitution:] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterSetSurfaceVelocity", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair setSurfaceVelocity:] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterSetUserData", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair setUserData:] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterTotalImpulse", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair totalImpulse] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpArbiterTotalKE", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair totalKineticEnergy] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpBodyAccumulateMassFromShapes", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsBody setAllowsRotation:] in CCPhysicsBody.o
  "_cpBodyEachArbiter_b", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsBody eachCollisionPair:] in CCPhysicsBody.o
  "_cpBodyGetCenterOfGravity", referenced from:
      ___21-[CCPhysicsNode draw]_block_invoke in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpBodyGetType", referenced from:
      ___21-[CCPhysicsNode draw]_block_invoke in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpBodyGetUserData", referenced from:
      _PhysicsBegin in CCPhysicsNode.o
      _PhysicsPreSolve in CCPhysicsNode.o
      _PhysicsPostSolve in CCPhysicsNode.o
      _PhysicsSeparate in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpBodyLocalToWorld", referenced from:
      ___21-[CCPhysicsNode draw]_block_invoke in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpBodySetVelocityUpdateFunc", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsBody setAffectedByGravity:] in CCPhysicsBody.o
  "_cpBodyUpdateVelocity", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsBody setAffectedByGravity:] in CCPhysicsBody.o
      _NotAffectedByGravity in CCPhysicsBody.o
  "_cpCircleShapeSetOffset", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCircleShape rescaleShape:] in CCPhysicsShape.o
  "_cpCircleShapeSetRadius", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCircleShape rescaleShape:] in CCPhysicsShape.o
  "_cpConstraintGetImpulse", referenced from:
      _BreakConstraint in CCPhysicsJoint.o
  "_cpConstraintSetPostSolveFunc", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsJoint setBreakingForce:] in CCPhysicsJoint.o
  "_cpPolyShapeSetRadius", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsPolyShape rescaleShape:] in CCPhysicsShape.o
  "_cpPolyShapeSetVerts", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsPolyShape rescaleShape:] in CCPhysicsShape.o
  "_cpSegmentShapeSetEndpoints", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsSegmentShape rescaleShape:] in CCPhysicsShape.o
  "_cpSegmentShapeSetRadius", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsSegmentShape rescaleShape:] in CCPhysicsShape.o
  "_cpShapeGetUserData", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsCollisionPair shapeA:shapeB:] in CCPhysicsNode.o
      ___43-[CCPhysicsNode pointQueryAt:within:block:]_block_invoke in CCPhysicsNode.o
      ___44-[CCPhysicsNode rayQueryFirstFrom:to:block:]_block_invoke in CCPhysicsNode.o
      ___33-[CCPhysicsNode rectQuery:block:]_block_invoke in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsNode handlerForTypeA:typeB:] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpSpaceAddWildcardHandler", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsNode handlerForTypeA:typeB:] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpSpaceBBQuery_b", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsNode rectQuery:block:] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpSpaceDebugDraw", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsNode draw] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpSpaceEachBody_b", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsNode draw] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpSpaceGetCurrentTimeStep", referenced from:
      _BreakConstraint in CCPhysicsJoint.o
  "_cpSpaceIsLocked", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsBody setType:] in CCPhysicsBody.o
  "_cpSpacePointQuery_b", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsNode pointQueryAt:within:block:] in CCPhysicsNode.o
  "_cpSpaceSegmentQuery_b", referenced from:
      -[CCPhysicsNode rayQueryFirstFrom:to:block:] in CCPhysicsNode.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added all Framework as it is but still getting error.

Comment: then your framework isn't 64 bit

Comment: try in device , simulator show this error

Comment: not working @Anbu,Karthik

Comment: i using xcode 6 so  i am  putting arm64 in valid architectures